# Out Of Memory Error | Deploying on WAS 8

Tags: out-of-memory, ibm-was

I am getting the following error while deploying an application on Websphere Application Server version 8.

```
SystemErr     R Exception in thread "server.startup : 0" com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:  [Root exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError]Exception in thread "Default : 1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryErrorjava.lang.OutOfMemoryErrorException in thread "ORB.thread.pool : 2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

In Websphere Application Server (WAS), do this by starting the server and opening the Administration Console and going to:

Servers -> [Server Type] -> [ServerName] -> Java and Process Management -> Process Definition -> Java Virtual Machine -> Adjust Initial heap size and Maximum Heap size accordingly.

[image]

Here's more info: [Solving memory problems in WebSphere applications](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0706_sun/0706_sun.html)